# Ошибка в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код на [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fVit0mMv),

Ошибка:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "X:\Рабочий стол\tic-tac-toe.py", line 156, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "X:\Рабочий стол\tic-tac-toe.py", line 149, in main
>     move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
>   File "X:\Рабочий стол\tic-tac-toe.py", line 104, in computer_move
>     for move in legal_movies(board):
> TypeError: legal_movies() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
> ```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

У вас несостыковка с набором параметров.
Определение функции - без аргументов:

```
def legal_movies():
    """Создает список доступных ходов."""
    moves = []
```

Однако вызываете вы её с аргументами:

```
    print('Я выберу поле номер', end=' ')
    for move in legal_movies(board):
        board[move] = computer
```

Поэтому вы получили ошибку, что передаете аргумент в функцию, которая не принимает аргументов.